# No audio after clean installation

Tags: 10.10, sound

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10, and I have no audio. My Windows partition has no problem with the audio card and an 10.04 32 bit version recognised the audio card after the install. This one apparently does too, but I don't know what should I tweak. What should I look into?

[image]

Comment: check the output tab as well and see what it is using (if it is set to headphones only, or speakers, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `alsamixer` in a terminal and check that all channels are not muted. You'll know because they have an `M` at the bottom of a slider. Press m on your keyboard to toggle the channel mute status.